# PHP Code Protection

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php website which I have developed for my client. He is saying to upload all the data to his server and then he will make the payment. Basically its first time that I am working with him and I dont trust him much to give him the complete code without the money. I also dont want to ask money as its not a good impression. So Is there a way something like iframe or javascript which I upload on his server and he dont find that website code is still on my server.Well He dont know anything about PHP. The end result would be like that
(I am using code Igniter)
client visit..  www.client.com
he click on www.client.com/a/b/c/d
he go to that page.

but on backend(or pratically) he is on www.myserver/a/b/c/d

on every page and link on www.client.com work like that same way

Please give me some suggestions

Comment: This is an [escrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escrow) question, not a coding question.

Comment: Basically my client is a web development firm. I have already give him a demo on my server. Now they want to show it to their client. so they cant use my domain.

Comment: @Hamza: If you want to make things easier for your client without losing control of your code, you can configure a subdomain of your client's site on your own server, so he can show your work.

Comment: Alfonso is right, use the domain tools to create a vhost on your server.

Answer (score 4):

I would upload it to my server, let him test it out, then ask for payment and finalize the process by putting it on his server and sending him a copy of the files.

Comment: OP said the client already demoed the functionality. The issue is exchanging product/funds at the same time. Nothing at all specific to code.

Answer (score 2):

Don't solve this with a code hack. Solve this with some interpersonal communication skills. If you plan to be a freelancer, you will need to develop trust and rapport, and this is the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Or be professional and use a respected escrow service. Developer's aren't known for their wit and charm :)

Comment: Speak for yourself! Wit and Charm is my tagline.

Answer (score 2):

To maintain full control of your code, set up your own server or rent one from a host such as Rackspace, Amazon, or GoDaddy.com. Upload your script to the server and provide a URL for you client to test it.

After he is satisfied, arrange a payment for services and deliver the code to him. You may also wish charge an extra fee to upload and configure your code on his server if that service was not covered in your original contract.

Keep the client's wishes in mind: He may mistrust you as much as you mistrust him. You will need to provide good-faith evidence to him that you completed the project before you can expect him to part with the cash. In such cases, you may wish to ask him to place the money in an escrow account, allowing a third party arbiter to judge if the details of the arrangement have been satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

If his server is running apache and has mod_rewrite enabled you can upload a .htaccess file that redirects everything to your server. (It will be kind of slow)

Something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (*.) http://address.to.your.server/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

However, AlienWebguy is right. You should not need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to rename and upload a php shell. A php shell can be useful for many things but you should take care where do you get a php shell. There are some that are infected with a trojan.